# Spark Java round each value in dataframe to two decimal places.

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in spark that has 10 columns and 100ish rows. Each cell in the dataframe contains a decimal number. I want to round all the decimal numbers to two decimal places. How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with the function `public static Column round(Column e, int scale)` :

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#round(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)

Comment: Uhh my bad all the values are stored in strings. Is there any way I can call a map function on the dataframe to convert all strings to doubles?